# Remapping multiple Mp4 videos into a single one with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, avconv

I'm interested in remapping multiple (6) MP4 videos into a high resolution final video according to lookup tables I calculated. The idea is convert 6 independent videos in a 360º video according to an equirectangular projection.

[image: Equirectangular image example]
[Example of equirectangular video here](http://support.video-stitch.com/hc/en-us/articles/203657036-What-is-equirectangular-)

Is there a way to do this remapping with ffmpeg or any other linux program?
Right now I'm extracting all the frames from the videos, creating the equirectangular individual images and joining them again into a video. There must be a better way for this...

**UPDATE:**

Following Mulyva's suggestion I first remap each individual video using the remap filter. Those parts of the panoramic video not covered are interpreted like chromakey pixels using:

```
ffmpeg -i videos/camera1.MP4 -i camera0_map_x_radius5.pgm -i camera0_map_y_radius5.pgm -lavfi remap -qscale 1 out0.MP4
```

[image: Camera0]

[image: Camera1]

Then I try to overlay them using the chomakey filter:

```
 ffmpeg -i out0.MP4 -i out1.MP4 -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x12da11:0.2:0.2[chromakey_res];[0:v][chromakey_res]overlay=eof_action=pass[out]" -map "[out]" out.mp4
```

As you can see, the final result has an undesirable green shadow. Any idea of how to remove it?

[image: Result]

Comment: Have you looked at the [remap](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter) filter?

Comment: Yes, it does what I want partially because i have multiple input files instead of a single one...  Maybe I could generate multiple output videos and then try to overlay them, but I would need to specify "transparent" regions for each video, that I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: You can use the `geq` filter to assign `0` alpha to the black border regions and `1` elsewhere. Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38578363/5726027). Depending on the processing speed of the remap filter, you may be able to do it in one command with multiple instances of remap.

Comment: Is the green due to the filter, or was it in the source video? I would suggest going the geq route.

Comment: I get the same result with your suggested approach. The green is due to the remap filter. It sets to "green" the pixels that are out of the bounds of the original image according to the x/y map, and I don't see an option to set them black. According to the wiki "Any datavalue in the ymap or xmap which value is higher then the *source* frame height or width is silently ignored, leaving a blank/chromakey pixel. This can safely be used as a feature to create overlays."
It May be due to compression artifacts?

Comment: Ok, what's the output of `ffprobe camera1.mp4`?

Comment: Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-05-15 12:16:37
  Duration: 00:00:05.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 46132 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2704x2028 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 46097 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-15 12:16:37
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder

Comment: Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-15 12:16:37
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-15 12:16:37
      handler_name    :  GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 12:16:02:28
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 10 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-15 12:16:37

Comment: handler_name    :  GoPro SOS
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3

Comment: Try `-lavfi [0]format=yuvj444p[b];[b][1][2]remap,format=yuvj444p` & `-color_range 2` in the first command

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with the synatx. Using ffmpeg -i videos/camera1.MP4 -i camera0_map_x_radius5.pgm -i camera0_map_y_radius5.pgm -lavfi [0]format=yuvj444p[b];[b][1][2] remap,format=yuvj444p -color_range 2 out0.MP4        i get     Filter format has an unconnected output

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i videos/camera1.MP4 -i camera0_map_x_radius5.pgm -i camera0_map_y_radius5.pgm -lavfi [0]format=yuvj444p[b];[b][1][2] remap,format=yuvj444p[out] -map [out] -color_range 2 out0.MP4`. Depending on your shell, you may have to quote the map argument.

Comment: OK. Done it... But same green shadow appears.. :(

Comment: Can you share two of the source videos?

Comment: Sure. I've uploaded the pgm for remapping too.https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/eed5754fe432e1cb07e924c3e63328aa20160921135814/10d493

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**#1** Generate individual videos.

```
ffmpeg -i camera0.mp4 -i camera0_map_x_radius5.pgm -i camera0_map_y_radius5.pgm 
       -filter_complex "color=white:2704x2028[c];[0]format=rgb24,split[vm][va];
         [va][c]overlay=shortest=1:format=rgb[ac];
         [vm][1][2]remap[m];
         [ac][1][2]remap[a];
         [m][a]alphamerge"
       -c:v qtrle c0.mov
```

This creates a remapped video with an aligned alpha channel.

**#2** Overlay remapped videos

```
ffmpeg -i c0.Mov -i c1.Mov -i c2.mov -i c3.mov -i c4.mov -i c5.mov 
       -filter_complex
         "[0][1]overlay=eof_action=pass[a];
          [a][2]overlay=eof_action=pass[b];
          [b][3]overlay=eof_action=pass[c];
          [c][4]overlay=eof_action=pass[d];
          [d][5]overlay=eof_action=pass"    out.mp4
```

(You may need fifo filters if the processing is slow)

Comment: Fantastic. That's exactly what I need and the results are perfect. Thanks a lot for your help