# Overlaying one video on another one, and making black pixels transparent

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use **FFMPEG** to create a video with one video overlayed on top another.

I have 2 MP4s.  I need to make all **BLACK pixels** in the **overlay** video **transparent** so that I can see the main video underneath it.

I found two ways to overlay one video on another:

First, the following positions the overlay in the center, and therefore, hides that portion of the main video beneath it:

```
    ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf "movie=2.mp4 [a]; [in][a] overlay=352:0 [b]" combined.mp4 -y
```

And, this one, places the overlay video on the left, but it's opacity is set to 50% so at least other one beneath it is visible:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[top]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom]; [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=0" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 out.mp4 -y
```

My goal is simply to make all black pixels in the overlay (2.mp4) completely transparent. How can this be done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The notional way to do this is to chroma-key the black out and then overlay, But as @MoDJ said, this likely won't produce satisfactory results. Neither will the method I suggest below, but it's worth a try.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex
"[1]split[m][a];
 [a]geq='if(gt(lum(X,Y),16),255,0)',hue=s=0[al];
 [m][al]alphamerge[ovr];
 [0][ovr]overlay"
output.mp4
```

Above, I duplicate the overlay video stream, then use the `geq` filter to manipulate the luma values so that any pixel with luma greater than 16 (i.e. not pure black) has its luma set to white, else zero. Since I haven't provided expressions for the two color channels, `geq` falls back on the luma expression. We don't want that, so I use the `hue` filter to nullify those channels. Then I use the `alphamerge` filter to merge this as an alpha channel with the first copy of the overlay video. Then, the overlay. Like I said, this may not produce satisfactory results. You can tweak the value `16` in the geq filter to change the black threshold. Suggested range is 16-24 for limited-range (Y: 16-235) video files.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. Admittedly, I don't quite follow the explanation and could never have come up with that simply by looking at FFMPEG documentation, which I find extremely cryptic.  I think the results are in fact satisfactory, but if my client disagrees, I will go with MoDJ's suggestion. (Thank you both!)

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get a "replace black pixels" approach to work properly. What you actually want is a foreground video with a real alpha channel that can be manipulated and tested before doing an overlay on a background. For an extended example that describes the problems, please take a look at my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen/) on the subject. When using FFMPEG, an easy way to import alpha channel video is to use Quicktime with the Animation codec video at 32 BPP.

Comment: I'm really new to all of this, and I find the syntax extremely confusing.  But, I'm told that I should be able to modify the blend mode in the overlay video to create the transparency.  Is that not doable?

Comment: See my blog post for the details, the problem is quality and the actual look of the final results. You need an input video with a full alpha channel.