# FFMPEG: How do I set the transparency color of an animated GIF for overlaying on a video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video clip that I've converted to an animated GIF with ffmpeg. I would like to overlay that animated GIF onto a video clip. The problem is I can't figure out how to set the transparency color of the GIF. I want the solid black background of the GIF to be transparent.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 output.gif
```

That's what I'm doing to created the animated GIF. Again, looks great. I just need to add black (#000000) as the transparent color of the GIF.

Thanks!

Comment: Apply the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38578363/5726027) in my answer to the GIF.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look!