# How can I overlay a transparent video(mp4) over an MP4?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I want to use one transparent video on video. But When I create a video at that time It displays a black background.

Ex. 
(Command)

```
 ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i Bg_file.mp4 -i transparent_img.png -re -stream_loop -1 -i transparent_video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=trunc(1080/2)*2:trunc(1080/2)*2[video];[1:v]scale=trunc(1080/2)*2:trunc(1080/2)*2[bg];[bg][video]overlay=0:0[bv];[1:v]scale=trunc(1080/2)*2:trunc(1080/2)*2[wf];[bv][wf]overlay=0:0[out0];[2:v] scale=200:400,rotate=-7:c=black@0:ow=rotw(-7):oh=roth(-7) [s1];[out0][s1]overlay=110:5[out1]" -t 7 -map [out1] -y -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

I want to video like this : [image]

But I got the video : [image]

How can I create a video?

Comment: The video isn't actually transparent. Adapt the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38581696 to process the `transparent_video.mp4`

Comment: is mp4 video transparent?

Comment: Not typically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H264 is unable to export aplha channel (transparency).